# Iniciar DatePicker com dia atual

Tags: jquery

Possuo um cadastro onde tenho duas datas sendo: `DataInicial` e `DataFinal`, estou usando o `DataPicker` para inserir ambas, como posso deixar a `DataInicial` sempre com a data de hoje, não posso permitir datas retroativas.
Vi algumas dicas como essa, mas não deu certo, vejam:

[Jquery Date picker Default Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6646376/jquery-date-picker-default-date)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tente isto:

`$('#datepicker').datepicker("setDate", new Date());`

```
<link href="http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="input-append date" id="datepicker" data-date="dateValue: Customer.DateOfBirth" data-date-format="dd-mm-yyyy">
<input class="span2" size="16" type="text" data-bind="value: Customer.DateOfBirth" readonly="readonly" />
<span class="add-on"><i class="icon-calendar"></i>
</span>
</div>
```

Veja funcionando no [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/D9Xav/1404/)

**Refencia:**

[Set today's date as default date in jQuery UI datepicker](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26894822/5524514)

[Bootstrap datepicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13377847/bootstrap-datepicker)

Comment: Olá @DiegoFelipe, fiz a alteração mas o campo não me mostra a data, onde o ID "#mydata" no meu caso chama-se "#DataInicial".

Comment: @adventistapr seu campo de data é um input tipo text correto?

Comment: Sim, ele está assim: <input name="dDataInicial" type="text" class="form-control" id="dDataInicial">

Comment: Vou adicionar um exemplo do mesmo post do SOen, veja se te ajuda.

Comment: Olá @DiegoFelipe, muda alguma coisa se disser que estou usando o DataPicker para Bootstrap?

Comment: @adventistapr mas o datepicker do bootstrap precisa de jquery. Veja os requisitos [**aqui**](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#requirements). Adicione `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>` após a lib js do bootstrap no seu código e veja se funciona.

Comment: @adventistapr editei a resposta, veja se agora funciona.

Answer (score 0):

```
 
$("#seu_campo_id").datepicker({defaultDate: "getDate()",
                      dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
                      dayNames: ['Domingo','Segunda','Terça','Quarta','Quinta','Sexta','Sábado','Domingo'],
                      dayNamesMin: ['D','S','T','Q','Q','S','S','D'],
                      dayNamesShort: ['Dom','Seg','Ter','Qua','Qui','Sex','Sáb','Dom'],
                      monthNames: ['Janeiro','Fevereiro','Março','Abril','Maio','Junho','Julho','Agosto','Setembro','Outubro','Novembro','Dezembro'],
                      monthNamesShort: ['Jan','Fev','Mar','Abr','Mai','Jun','Jul','Ago','Set','Out','Nov','Dez'],
                      changeMonth: false,
                      numberOfMonths: 1,
                      minDate: 0}).datepicker("setDate", new Date());
```

Comment: Uma pequena explicação do código ajudava.